# Error near '='...help me how to remove it

Tags: sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure35
    @Deal_ID int
AS
    select
        d.Deal_Price,
        i.Item_Name
    from
        Deals d,
        Items i,
        DealItemRelation r
    where
        d.Deal_ID = r.Deal_ID
        &
        i.Item_ID = r.Item_ID
        &
        d.Deal_ID = @d.Deal_ID
```

Comment: What a strange C# code

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&` with `AND`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure35 @Deal_ID int 
AS SELECT d.Deal_Price,i.Item_Name FROM Deals d,Items i,DealItemRelation r 
   WHERE d.Deal_ID=r.Deal_ID AND i.Item_ID=r.Item_ID AND d.Deal_ID=@Deal_ID
```